# ¿Códigos para hacer que tablas se desplacen?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo tres tablas diferentes en una hoja de Excel, y estoy programando con Visual Basic.

Lo que quiero es que a partir de un Combo Box, elija una de las tres tablas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He aquí la inquietud:

Quiero lograr que al momento de realizar una captura, si en mi ComboBox selecciono "Buzón Gris", me posicione en esa tabla y capture datos.

El problema sería que si selecciono después agregar datos en "Buzón Azul" obviamente la selección se habrá movido por agregar en el buzón Gris (por estar arriba del azul).

¿Es posible hacer que el programa reconozca que se ingresaron filas para situar la selección el inicio de la tabla?

Private Sub Guard_Click()

```
If ComboBuzón = "Buzón Gris: Metales" Then

    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert

        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2) = CapturistaCamp
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3) = Hora
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4) = Día
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 5) = cmb_Clima
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6) = Total
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 7) = Nivel
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 8) = Algodón
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 10) = Fibras
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 12) = Cerámica
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 14) = Textil
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 16) = Cuero
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 18) = Hule
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 20) = Cartón
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 22) = CartónNo
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 24) = Tetra
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 26) = Papel
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 28) = Madera
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 30) = Jardín
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 32) = Alimen
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 34) = Carne
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 36) = Hueso
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 38) = Lata
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 40) = Ferroso
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 42) = Construcción
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 44) = Bolsa
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 46) = BolsaColor
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 48) = Unicel
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 50) = PET
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 52) = PETno
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 54) = HDPE
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 56) = Duro
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 58) = VidrioColor
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 60) = Vidrio
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 62) = Sanitario
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 64) = Repe
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 66) = Relec
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 68) = Refin
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 70) = Otro
End If

    If ComboBuzón = "Buzón Azul: PET y Plástico" Then

    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert

        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2) = CapturistaCamp
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3) = Hora
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4) = Día
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 5) = cmb_Clima
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6) = Total
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 7) = Nivel
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 8) = Algodón
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 10) = Fibras
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 12) = Cerámica
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 14) = Textil
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 16) = Cuero
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 18) = Hule
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 20) = Cartón
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 22) = CartónNo
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 24) = Tetra
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 26) = Papel
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 28) = Madera
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 30) = Jardín
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 32) = Alimen
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 34) = Carne
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 36) = Hueso
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 38) = Lata
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 40) = Ferroso
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 42) = Construcción
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 44) = Bolsa
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 46) = BolsaColor
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 48) = Unicel
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 50) = PET
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 52) = PETno
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 54) = HDPE
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 56) = Duro
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 58) = VidrioColor
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 60) = Vidrio
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 62) = Sanitario
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 64) = Repe
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 66) = Relec
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 68) = Refin
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 70) = Otro
End If
```

End Sub

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido. Por favor, sustituye la segunda imagen por el codigo en formato texto ^^ un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para que vba "reconozca" en qué fila está la tabla, lo más sencillo sería poner una celda con un valor distintivo en cada tabla, por ej. tabla1 y hacer que vba busque la fila de esa celda con el método Cells.Find y así consigues la fila para empezar a trabajar. No sé si esto te puede ayudar.